# How to display the value from my form?

Tags: jquery

Please can someone tell me why my code is not working? I'm very new to jquery and am trying to get a value from an input field into jquery variable that I can use.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/7o5dzm4r/). Thanks.

The html

```
<form id="form" method="post">
<input type="text" id="cost" placeholder ="enter a number between 0 & 100"  />
 <input type="submit">



<div id="gauge" class="200x160px"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function() {
value = $("#cost").val(); 

//Display value in justgage
   var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    value: value,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });

    });


 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you need to

- load jQuery in the JSFiddle
- preventDefault the submission
- have a place for gauge to put the result
- not create a new gauge every time you submit

Here is a working code that sets the new value if a gauge already exists

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vzwmbaxh/)

```js
var g;
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  value = $("#cost").val();
  
  //Display JustGage
  if (!g) {
    g = new JustGage({
      id: "gauge",
      value: value,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "Visitors"
    });
  }
  else g.refresh(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/justgage/1.0.1/justgage.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="cost" placeholder="enter number from 0 - 100" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="gauge">

</div>
```

Comment: This is great, Thank you. Can you tell me why the gage re-displays itself if I press the submit button more than once? How can this be avoided?

Comment: Not on my computer (running Chrome) with the code I provided

Comment: Just seen your fiddle and the refresh code. Works great. Thank you.